# What's the coding standard for class constants?

Tags: coding-standards

For general constants, [Coding standards / Naming Conventions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards#naming) says that constants should always be all-uppercase, with underscores to separate words and that module-defined constant names should also be prefixed by the module module machine name, all-uppercase, and an underscore character.

Object-oriented names don't follow the normal conventions of prefixing the name with the module or using underscores; instead, they opt for various forms of camel case.

Unfortunately, [Object-oriented code](http://drupal.org/node/608152) doesn't mention class constants at all.

Which of the following is correct?

- `const FOO_CONSTANT_VALUE = 'bar';`
- `const CONSTANT_VALUE = 'bar';`
- `const constantValue = 'bar';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct one would be:

```
class Foo {
  const CONSTANT_VALUE = 'bar';
}
```

For example, quoting after [Zend Framework naming conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html#coding-standard.naming-conventions.constants) (however there are many others for different frameworks, just Google around):

> Constants may contain both alphanumeric characters and underscores.
>   Numbers are permitted in constant names.
>
> All letters used in a constant name must be capitalized, while all
>   words in a constant name must be separated by underscore characters.
>
> For example, EMBED_SUPPRESS_EMBED_EXCEPTION is permitted but
>   EMBED_SUPPRESSEMBEDEXCEPTION is not.
>
> Constants must be defined as class members with the "const" modifier.
>   Defining constants in the global scope with the "define" function is
>   permitted but strongly discouraged.

It does not explicitely say anything about `FOO_CONSTANT_VALUE` vs `CONSTANT_VALUE`, but not using class name in constant name is general practice. Which perfectly makes sense, considering that you are in class scope.

Answer (score 1):

What reported from the Drupal coding standards about constants is still valid for constants defined in classes. The only difference is that constants defined from a class don't need any prefix that identify the module that defines the constants; that prefix would be eventually added to the class name.

There isn't the need to add a prefix that is derived from the class name to the constant name, as `Foo::CONSTANT_NAME` is different from `Bar::CONSTANT_NAME`, and PHP will not throw an error when both the constants are defined.